# yaml-cpp : How to read this yaml file content using c++ /Linux (using yaml-cpp version = 0.6.3 )

Tags: c++, linux, yaml-cpp

i am trying to read each Node and its  respective content (yaml content is below)
I am ending up with belwo error .

**Error:** terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YAML::TypedBadConversion

sample code :

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile('yamlfile');
std::cout << config["Circles"]["x"].as<std::int64_t>();
```

Also i tried with some other approach but perhaps this yaml formt  is complex one . I could read a sample format of yaml but not the one i have mentioned below .

Any helping hand ?

sample.yaml

```
- Pos: sensor - pos1
  Rectangle:
    - x: -0.2
      y: -0.13
      z: 3.26
    - x: 0.005
      y: -0.13
      z: 3.2
    - x: -0.2
      y: 0.10
      z: 3.26
    - x: 0.00
      y: 0.10
      z: 3.2
```

Comment: `'yamlfile'` should be `"yamlfile"` - Increase your compiler's warning level to catch typos like this. `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors` is a good start. Also, the filename `yamlfile` does not match `sample.yaml` and `sample.yaml` does not contain `Circles` which makes it throw `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YAML::TypedBadConversion<long>'`

Comment: Basically my code and yaml content are not matching here intensionaly . sorry but not added exact code . buy yes the code and yaml string are matching including proper file name .I had make sure this basic stuff are correct .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question does not match the `sample.yaml` file you've provided but here's an example of how you could extract the floating points you have in the `Rectangle` in `sample.yaml`.

```cpp
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    try {
        YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("sample.yaml");

        // The outer element is an array
        for(auto dict : config) {
            // The array element is a map containing the Pos and Rectangle keys:
            auto name = dict["Pos"];
            std::cout << "Name: " << name << '\n';

            auto rect = dict["Rectangle"];

            // loop over the positions Rectangle and print them:
            for(auto pos : rect) {
                std::cout << pos["x"].as<double>() << ",\t"
                          << pos["y"].as<double>() << ",\t"
                          << pos["z"].as<double>() << '\n';
            }
        }

    } catch(const YAML::BadFile& e) {
        std::cerr << e.msg << std::endl;
        return 1;
    } catch(const YAML::ParserException& e) {
        std::cerr << e.msg << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Name: sensor - pos1
0.2,    -0.13,  3.26
0.005,  -0.13,  3.2
-0.2,   0.1,    3.26
0,      0.1,    3.2
```

Comment: Reading was success. Thanks for your effort Ted Lyngmo

Comment: @Hosen Glad it worked! You're welcome!